# Json Boolean value expression issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, ios6

**My Response: (JSON)**

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData4 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"responseString... %@",responseString);

 {"AT":"dMaOtJxV0EgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA","DId":320,"EMs":null,"Em":null,"LGT":null,"OS":"Success","PWD":"DEBC0C7321EF1386F7F22A3D8BE754C9FF04A596","SId":0,"Sku":"Director","UId":1664,"UN":"s1","COM":null,"DN":null,"DOS":null,"EA":"s+1@gmail.com","FN":"s","IsCon":true,"IsLT":true,"IsPU":false,"IsSuc":false,"IsSync":true,"IsTri":false,"LLD":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/","LN":"k","MOD":null,"NDD":"\/Date(1376971200000-0400)\/","NDDS":"8\/20\/2013","PN":"(324) 325-4353","SD":"s","SLT":"HBoY7mHJ","STs":"EN","UQId":null,"US":3,"Ver":null}
```

I have to fetch IsPU,IsCon tag value here.

Then I have written code like

```
NSError *error;

id jsonMain = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData4 options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSString *IsPUstring = [jsonMain objectForKey:@"IsPU"];

NSString *IsConstring = [jsonMain objectForKey:@"IsCon"];


NSLog(@"IsPUstring...%@",IsPUstring);

NSLog(@"IsConstring...%@",IsConstring);
```

**Output:**

> IsPUstring... 0
>
> IsConstring... 1

**My Issue:**

Original Tag value:

> "IsCon":true,"IsPU":false

But after JSON serialization it's changed to 0 and 1 right?

Is there any way to get my original value like true or false here?

Comment: may i know the necessary of getting like 'true' or 'false'???

Comment: If you want 'true' or 'false' just use condition if([IsPUstring isequaltostring:@"0"])IsPUstring=@"false";remaining are same like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get it like bellow..

```
 BOOL  IsPUstring  = [[jsonMain objectForKey:@"IsPU"] boolValue];
 BOOL IsConstring = [[jsonMain objectForKey:@"IsCon"] boolValue];

NSLog(@"IsPUstring...%d",IsPUstring);

NSLog(@"IsConstring...%d",IsConstring);
```

**If you want to get this value in `NSString` format then you can use bellow code also..**

```
NSLog(@"IsPUstring... %s", IsPUstring ? "true" : "false");
NSLog(@"IsConstring... %s", IsConstring ? "true" : "false");
```

Answer (score 0):

0 and 1 *are* NO and YES. A boolean object in JSON data will be converted to an NSNumber*, and the NSNumber method [aNumber boolValue] will return YES and NO.

Now an integer with a value of lets say 0, 1 or 2 will also be converted to an NSNumber*, and for these three values [aNumber boolValue] will return NO for 0, YES for 1, and YES for 2 (it will return YES for any number that is not zero).

If you really want to distinguish between false / true and 0 / 1:

```
NSNumber* isPU = jsonMain [@"IsPU"];

if (isPU == (id) kCFBooleanFalse) { ... } // isPU is false and not 0 or "0"
else if (isPU == (id) kCFBooleanTrue) { ... } // isPU is true and not 1 or "1"
else { ... } // isPU is something else.
```